# How do I convert the month and day in dataset to datetime so that I can index it?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

End goal: I want to create a graph so that the x-axis is the date and there are two y-axis, one Ontario and one CMB. Ultimately there would be 5 graphs (Ontario,2 vs CMB,2 & Ontario,3 vs CMB,3 & etc.)

[Ideal Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4iMp.png)

However, my datasets have date as "mm-dd" in the Datestamp column which are object type. Also, both tables do not have all the same dates.

```
dfplot_ont.tail()

    Datestamp   Ontario,2   Ontario,3   Ontario,4   Ontario,5   Ontario,7
18  12-29   -0.664715   0.245738    0.668187    0.016819    -0.493384
19  12-30   0.491311    0.302230    1.140404    1.421685    1.552911
20  01-02   1.213827    0.471704    1.400124    1.599767    1.621120
21  01-03   1.502834    0.048018    0.927907    0.956694    1.052705
22  01-04   -1.965244   -2.917788   0.597355    0.234474    -0.857170


dfplot_cmb.tail()

    Datestamp   CMB,2           CMB,3           CMB,4           CMB,5           CMB,7
15  12-28   0.907092    0.937362    0.991568    1.030808    1.139708
16  12-29   0.900410    0.919994    0.992267    0.991359    1.034978
17  12-30   1.181259    1.193806    1.272700    1.283576    1.265860
18  01-03   0.751646    0.752037    0.681900    0.686982    0.600167
19  01-04   0.606714    0.532544    0.339825    0.282894    0.127186
```

I need to change this to datetime but it seems like I need to include a year to change it. How do I code "if the month is 12, then year is 2022 and if the month is 1, then year is 2023"? I will also need to swap it out for the year will always be 2023 once there is data at the end of the year.

I have tried this, but it does not change Datestamp to datetime type:

```
dfplot_ont['Datestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dfplot_ont['Datestamp'], format='%m-%d').dt.strftime('%m-%d')
```

I have also tried this, but then the index ends up not being mm-dd:

```
dfplot_ont = dfplot_ont.set_index(pd.to_datetime(dfplot_ont['Datestamp'], format='%MM-%dd'))

                    Datestamp   Ontario,2     Ontario,3    Ontario,4    Ontario,5      Ontario,7
Datestamp                       
1900-01-22 00:12:00 12-22   0.708066      -0.149703    -0.724853    -1.200072      -0.356965
1900-01-23 00:12:00 12-23   -0.520212     0.415213     -1.362347    -1.140712      -0.970853
1900-01-26 00:12:00 12-26   -0.014450     0.612933     -1.149849    -0.952737      -0.925380
1900-01-27 00:12:00 12-27   0.202305      0.669425     -1.102627    -0.893376      -0.925380
1900-01-28 00:12:00 12-28   -0.953721     0.302230     -0.394301    -0.042542      0.302397
```

I tried this as well, but similar to above, datestamp is not correct:

```
dfplot_cmb\['Datestamp'\] = pd.to_datetime(dfplot_cmb\['Datestamp'\], format='%M-%d')
dfplot_cmb.set_index('Datestamp', inplace=True)
dfplot_cmb.head()

                        CMB,2           CMB,3           CMB,4           CMB,5           CMB,7

Datestamp                   
1900-01-19 00:12:00 -1.559724   -1.663136   -1.719869   -1.771499   -1.778253
1900-01-20 00:12:00 -1.311374   -1.250774   -1.156484   -1.076946   -1.038540
1900-01-21 00:12:00 -1.220269   -1.156733   -1.106780   -1.077736   -1.057990
1900-01-22 00:12:00 -0.554371   -0.517907   -0.513658   -0.517146   -0.498735
1900-01-23 00:12:00 0.298617    0.252807    0.218531    0.167709    0.205619
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I code "if the month is 12, then year is 2022 and if the month is 1, then year is 2023"?

First, create a function to implement the above logic:

```
import datetime

def create_dt(ds): 
  mm = ds[:2]
  dd = ds[-2:]
  # Modify logic accordingly if you have other months 
  if month == '01': 
    dt = f'2023-{mm}-{dd}'
  else: 
    dt = f'2022-{mm}-{dd}'
  return datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Then apply this function to column `Datestamp` to crate a new column:

```
dfplot_ont['datetime']= dfplot_ont['Datestamp'].apply(create_dt)
```

Use the new column `datetime` as your x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that will add an offset for each year.

```
data = {'date': ['12-29', '12-30', '12-31', '01-02', '01-03', '01-04']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Set a start year. In this case we'll start at 2022.

```
start_year = 2022

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(  df['date'].str.slice(0,2) + '-' 
                            + df['date'].str.slice(3,5) + '-' 
                            + str(start_year)
                           )
```

Next we need to create a date offset to increment each year accordingly. Whenever the current month is less than the previous month, we know we've started a new year. We can turn this into a Boolean and cumulatively sum it to get each year's offset.

```
df['offset'] = df['date'].dt.month.lt(df['date'].dt.month.shift()).cumsum()
```

Without `cumsum()`, the data looks like this. You can see how we cumulatively sum each time the year changes.

```
        date  offset
0 2022-12-29  False
1 2022-12-30  False
2 2022-12-31  False
3 2022-01-02  True
4 2022-01-03  False
5 2022-01-04  False
```

Finally, we add the offset to the date by year.

```
df['date'] = df['date'] + df['offset'].astype('timedelta64[Y]')

        date  offset
0 2022-12-29       0
1 2022-12-30       0
2 2022-12-31       0
3 2023-01-02       1
4 2023-01-03       1
5 2023-01-04       1
```